# How to Run A Java Program With Multiple External Jar Files In Linux [Error: Could not find or load main class]

Tags: java, linux, git, jar, git-bash

I have a Windows 10 and have been using Git Bash for a linux environment because it was mandatory.

My java file and jar files are in the same directory where I run git bash.

I have used to compile a java program that used multiple jars

> javac -cp \* Program.java

After compiling the program, I have been trying to run the program with multiple external jars using

> java -cp .:\* Program

However as a result I receive the following error message

> Error: Could not find or load main class Program

I'm pretty sure the way I went about this is correct and need help figuring out what is wrong.

Comment: try ``java -cp .:/* Program``
I feel you have used wrong slash..

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```sh
java -cp "_YOUR_PATH_TO_LIBS/*:_OTHER_PATH_TO_LIBS/*" yourpackage.YourClassName
```

Here is my example of `start.sh` file:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

DIR=`dirname $0`

java -Xmx400m -cp "$DIR/libs/*:$DIR/resources" com.myapp.Main
```

Comment: Sorry, what's the meaning of  yourpackage.yourclassName?

Comment: Its an example name of main class (with `public static void main(String[] args)` method)  located in `yourpackage` package.